# Visual Studio 2022, missing "Fix all occurrences" option in refactoring menu

Tags: visual-studio

Currently I am using Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise. I have few rules defined in my .editorconfig. One of the rule is that all the private variables should be camelcase and shouldn't start with underscore (_). Now I have few instances in the code where the private variables using underscore. When I open the refactoring menu by hitting Ctrl+. on those instances, VS only gives me option to fix that instance. For some reason "Fix all occurrences in" Documents | Projects | Solution is missing.

[image]

Anyone got an idea why is that option not showing up and how can I fix that?

Thanks.